# Why using django TemplateTag tag?

Tags: django, templates, syntax, templatetag

I have been reading some django code recently and the tag Templatetag is heavily used :

```
  {% templatetag openblock %} block page_title {% templatetag closeblock %}
  Page Title 
  {% templatetag openblock %} endblock page_title {% templatetag closeblock %}
```

what are the advantages over the shorter syntax below :

```
  {% block page_title %}Page Title{% endblock %}
```

documentation says that templatetag can be use for:

```
openblock   {%
closeblock  %}
openvariable {{;
closevariable }};
openbrace {;
closebrace };
opencomment {#;
closecomment #};
```

for me, it just make code longer, so in which case should i use it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those aren't the same at all. The `templatetag` tag outputs the *literal* characters. So the first one actually renders in the output as `{% block page_title %}`, whereas the second one interprets the tag and renders the block.

I don't know how your template was used, but looks as though it was dynamically outputting another template that will then be rendered in turn.

Answer (score 2):

It is useful to create project templates, because the pre-processor of the "startproject" command will process these symbols ({%, {{ etc) and remove them incorrectly without this approach.

Example: https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project/blob/develop/project_name/templates/base.html